# How do I remove the string in brackets only from the beginning of the entire string?

Tags: javascript, regex, string, replace

I have tried using replace for removing the string in the brackets. But this doesnt work. I want to remove only in the beginning brackets.

```
var string="(I want to delete this) helloo (not this)";
var replacedString=string.replace(/ *\([^)]*\) */g, "");
```

Comment: Don't use the g modifier and anchor the pattern with `^`.

Comment: or if its always in that format `string = string.substr(string.indexOf(')') + 1);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could look for the first bracket at start and for a closing bracket of the string and then replace it.

```js
var string = "(I want to delete this) helloo (not this)",
    result = string.replace(/^\([^)]*\)/, '');

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below regex, without /g flag

```
\((.+?)\)
```

You will get the result in group 1 if you want to preserve brackets,

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/nAU1yK/3/)

Answer (score 0):

This should work in most, if not all, instances:

`myString.replace(/\((.*?)\)/, '$1')`